# driver.press_keycode(84):global name 'driver' is not defined

Tags: python, automation, appium

I'm beginner in Appium automation,I trying sent messages but have some errors,hope someone help me.

I use "send_keys("0911111111")" it just print into the textbox but can't search and it didn't have search button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqdwI.jpg

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

# Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
)

class ContactsAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        #desired_caps['automationName'] = 'UiAutomator1'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '10.0'
        desired_caps['udid'] = '8BLAY00DSD'        
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Pixel 3a'
        #desired_caps['app'] = PATH('D:/appium/app/ContactManager.apk')
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.google.android.apps.messaging'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.ui.ConversationListActivity'


        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    def tearDown(self):
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.quit()


    def test_text_friend(self):

        search_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.apps.messaging:id/action_zero_state_search").click()


        name_search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.apps.messaging:id/zero_state_search_box_auto_complete")
        name_search_bar.send_keys("0911111111")
        driver.press_keycode(84)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite =  
    unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ContactsAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: The errors message :
est_text_friend (__main__.ContactsAndroidTests) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_text_friend (__main__.ContactsAndroidTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "messge.py", line 38, in test_text_friend
    driver.press_keycode(84)
NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: `driver.press...` -> `self.driver.press...`?

Comment: It work but it doesn't use the search keycode why?

Comment: There is no "driver" by itself, only driver belonging to that class, hence `self.driver`. It's possible you didn't want the driver itself but one of the elements you extract before that - `search_button` or `name_search_bar`.

Comment: after i change my code """        name_search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.apps.messaging:id/zero_state_search_box_auto_complete")
        name_search_bar.send_keys("091111111")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.press_keycode(84)

Comment: After running no error, but search keyboard not working,its my keyborad need to change?